# Finding the ranges values of k

Tags: abstract-algebra

The profit per day, in RM, of a shop is given by P = n^2-10n+k+45, where k is a constant and n is the number of products sold by the shop. Find the range of values of k if the shop must earn the profit at least RM 600 per day.

This was a question set in my Additional Mathematics examination. I have tried it many times, but  I still couldn't get the answers. Hope you can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would read the question to require that the profit be at least $600$ regardless of the value of $n$.  The worst case is when $n^2-10n$ is minimized, which comes at $n=5$.  In that case the profit is $k+20$, so we must have $k \ge 580$

Comment: I'm sorry. I couldn't understand. Can u explain in a more detail?

Comment: Do you see why $n^2-10n$ is minimized at $n=5?$.  If not, you should plot it.  It is an upward parabola.

Comment: I undertand that, but why should we just minimize n^2-10n ? And why should we just mnimize n^2-10n only and not the whole expression.

Comment: For a given $k$ the only variable left is $n$, so minimizing over $n$ will give the minimum of the whole expression.  The addition of $k+45$ just changes the minimum, not the value of $n$ where it is achieved.

Comment: Oh i see. But why do we need to minimize n^2-10n ? Is it because the profit must be at least 600.

Comment: That is right.  As I said, we require that the profit be at least $600$ for any $n$.  If we make sure it is $600$ for the $n$ that makes it lowest, it will be greater for any other $n$.